# Is there a fast painless way to setup a linux distro on VirtualBox?

Tags: repository, virtualbox, virtualization

I like the Docker Hub with dockerfiles idea very much.

Is there a similar way to get a small working linux VirtualBox instance in a few commands, that could also be controlled from a command line?

Comment: Take a look at vagrantup.com vagrant does what you want and much more. It offeres a simple way to automatically setup preconfigured virtual machines. By default it works with VirtualBox. You can use boxes from hashicorps atlas to get started quickly https://atlas.hashicorp.com/boxes/search

Comment: @MarcelMeißner, cool, that looks exactly what I wanted. Please, turn it into an answer, so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vagrant is a great tool that does just what you want and much more! It's a ruby application written for fast and simple setup of minimal development environments.
By default it creates VirtualBox images, but it supports VMWare and many others too. The whole setup of a box is managed by a single Vagrantfile! Your vm options, network settings and provisioning is done there.
Setting up a virtualbox box is as easy as executing **just two** shell commands. Checkout the [Getting Started Guide](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/getting-started/) for an example using Ubuntu.
You can use a vast range of prepared images from the [Hashicorp Atlas](https://atlas.hashicorp.com/boxes/search) or build your owns.

Also, vagrant doesn't limit you to one virtual machine per development setup, it enables you to model cluster setups on a single machine using multiple vms. I myself use docker for that part though.
Edit: fixed a typo :<